# How can I implement ADFS with a Heroku Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

Our company has a Rails application hosted on Heroku. It currently uses Devise for user authentication.

One of our clients wants to know if their users could access our application using their ADFS implementation.

1. Would we be able to use Heroku Integrated security with Identity
   Federation?
2. Would we need a 3rd party like Auth0?
3. Can Devise use ADFS?
4. Should we use OmniAuth SAML?

Not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I work at Stormpath, we provide an addon service in the Heroku webstore: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/stormpath

Stormpath lets you store users and authenticate them against the typical username/password stuff, AD / LDAP, SAML providers, social login providers, etc.

It pretty much supports all of the stuff you'd want to do around authentication / authorization.

Now: the way the AD stuff works is pretty cool. You have to have your client install an AD agent on their network which will basically create a reverse tunnel between their network and Stormpath.

That agent will then copy over user data into Stormpath (usrenames, email, groups, etc.), but NOT password hashes.

When a user authenticates against your site, and you make the request to Stormpath -- we'll basically talk to your AD server over that tunnel, authenticate the user against your AD server, then return a 'standardized' Stormpath Account model to make it easier to work with.

All in all: it's a really nice solution that works really well in production.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently using Devise - would I have to stop using it?

Comment: No, you could use Stormpath just to sync your AD users.